# Attempts to update a custom object using the default user on a force.com site returning 401

Tags: force.com-sites, security

I am attempting to integrate Twilio with Salesforce to provide telephony based access for field staff. I have configured the site and have a custom controller that successfully queries custom Salesforce SObjects, but when I attempt to update a custom SObject, the site returns a 401 (auth) error.

Note that the Twilio HTTP POST call to the site uses the site’s Default User, which has visibility to all fields on the custom SObject and the site’s guest user (public access) profile has full CRUD rights on the custom SObject.

Any insight into why I get a 401 when attempting to update the SObject that the guest user appears to have all the visibility and access privileges to update?